# Teams Tab is not able to load in Teams Desktop Application using Microsoft Teams Toolkit

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, microsoft-teams, typescript

[image]

**My app is visible in ms team application when open in browser**

[image]

**My application is not visible in MS team desktop application**

Please help to resolve my error in Team Desktop application

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint URL cannot be used directly, so when configuring your tabs, try to use this format for contentURL and websiteURL:

```
contentUrl = {{siteUrl}}/_layouts/15/teamslogon.aspx?SPFX=true&dest={{sitePath}}

websiteUrl = {{siteUrl}}
```

**Ref and more details at:** [Custom Teams app works in browser app but not in the desktop app](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/custom-teams-app-works-in-browser-app-but-not-in-desktop-app/m-p/1008874)

Comment: when i am changing the content Url and website Url to that format , my application is not visible in the desktop Teams application as well as in the browser Teams Application